# Why the output difference here when comparing arrays in two different ways

Tags: php, arrays

I'm comparing arrays with `array_diff_key` and `array_diff_ukey`  but the output is different from both arrays. Manual says there is not difference b/w both function except the later one accpet a callback but I got the difference in output.

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "");

print_r($result = array_diff_key($array1, $array2));

$result = array_diff_ukey($array1, $array2, function($key1, $key2) {
                                    if ($key1 == $key2)
                                        return 0;
                                    elseif ($key1 > $key2)
                                        return 1;
                                    else
                                        return -1;
                    });

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => green
    [2] => red
)
Array
(
    [2] => red
)
```

Comment: From manual: `The two keys from the key => value pairs are considered equal only if (string) $key1 === (string) $key2 . In other words a strict type check is executed so the string representation must be the same.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using the `==` operator in your callback. When comparing strings, you should always use `===`.

```
var_dump("b" == 0);
> true
```

You can see for yourself by modifying your callback to output the equal keys:

```
if ($key1 == $key2)
{
    echo $key1 . " == " . $key2 . " = " . var_export($key1 == $key2, true) . "<br>";
    return 0;
}
```

Will result in:

```
0 == a = true
a == 0 = true
0 == b = true
b == 0 = true
a == 0 = true
0 == b = true
1 == 1 = true
```

The reason being that when you compare and int vs a string with `==` they will both be casted to an int value; so "a" becomes 0.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

`array_diff_*` version of function compare values/keys by first casting them in string type and compare then.

so my callback should be

```
$result = array_diff_ukey($array1, $array2, function($key1, $key2) {
                                    if ((string) $key1 == (string) $key2)
                                        return 0;
                                    elseif ($key1 > $key2)
                                        return 1;
                                    else
                                        return -1;
                    });
```